# White pixels around iOS Image using CIFilter

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimage, cifilter

I add a picture frame (Image with transparent background) around an existing UIImage and save it all as one image.  On simulator, everything looks like it runs great.  However on the device, it adds some white pixels around some of the areas of the frame's image.  Here is my code:

```
- (void)applyFilter {
    NSLog(@"Running");

    UIImage *borderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_8055.PNG"];

    NSData *dataFromImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imgView.image, 1);

    CIImage *beginImage= [CIImage imageWithData:dataFromImage];

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *border =[CIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(borderImage)];
    border = [border imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(beginImage.extent.size.width/border.extent.size.width, beginImage.extent.size.height/border.extent.size.height)];

    CIFilter *filter= [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceOverCompositing"];  //@"CISoftLightBlendMode"];
    [filter setDefaults];
    [filter setValue:border forKey:@"inputImage"];

    [filter setValue:beginImage forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];

    CIImage *outputImage = [filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];







    CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
    UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

    self.imgView.image = newImg;

}
```

Here is the resulting image:

[image]

The frame image used in the picture looks like this:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the frame image in photoshop, showing those pixels are not present in the PNG.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that if you look at your image, those pixels immediately adjacent to the musical notes are apparently not transparent. And if you notice, those white pixels that appear in the final image aren't just the occasional pixel, but they appear in square blocks.

These sorts of squared-off pixel noise is a telltale sign of JPEG artifacts. It's hard to say what's causing this because the image you added to this question was a JPEG (which doesn't support transparency). I assume you must have a PNG version of this backdrop? You might have to share that with us to confirm this diagnosis.

But the bottom line is that you need to carefully examine the original image and the transparency of those pixels that appear to be white noise. Make sure that as you create/manipulate these images, avoid JPEG file formats, because it loses transparency information and introduces artifacts. PNG files are often safer.

Comment: The original is a transparent PNG.  In simulator, the white doesn't appear.

Comment: Definitely not the issue.  Just opened the PNG in PHOTOSHOP and zoomed in to confirm transparent except for notes and title at top.  Will add a screenshot showing this in OP

Comment: @user717452 - I ran your code with my own images and didn't experience the artifacts that you describe. I'd suggest that you double check the PNG image sitting in your app's bundle and make sure it's like the one you verified in Photoshop. Perhaps edit the question to include the actual images so we can reproduce the behavior you describe. Until we can reproduce the behavior, we can't help you. And my attempts with your code and my own images worked fine.

Comment: @user717452 - What's curious about the OP is that the image labeled "The frame image used in the picture looks like this..." actually suffers the same JPEG-artifact-like noise that your combined image does (it's admittedly more subtle, with the white background, but zoom in and look extremely carefully at it and you'll see what I mean). It's got noise that your Photoshop rendition apparently doesn't. Bottom line, it really looks like it's gone through some JPEG process, that would manifest itself exactly like how your combined image is rendering.